# selecting identically named columns from different tables using wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have multiple tables (with slightly different names), with identical column names, that I join to a number of other unique tables. I then use Case to select data from these tables to omit null values:

e.g. `CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE x` etc etc.

However I am concerned that my queries are slow due to the high number of case functions I have to include. Every time there is a change in our forms, a new copy of this form table is produced, and for historic reporting I have to query each copy to obtain the relevant data into a single column for each "group" of columns. I also have a table that stores the names (and IDs) of all tables & was wondering whether I could use a wildcard to query this table to automatically query all historic tables. As all the column headers are the same, I was hoping to use a subquery like:

```
SELECT x, y, x FROM (
    SELECT form_name FROM table_of_table_names
        WHERE form_name LIKE '%mytypeofform%'
```

And I could then join this data as normal, but obviously the above doesn't work. This would also avoid me having edit my queries every time a change occurred. It could be that what I'm trying to achieve is no faster than my full outer joins & multiple case functions, but every time I add an additional case function the reports appear to run much slower. I am informed that I should be using dynamic SQL but have very little experience with this. Thanks!

Additional info:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID AS 'Case ID', FLODS_CLASSIFICATION_D00.TYPE AS 'Type', 
CASE WHEN FLODS_101000385_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000386_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000488_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000489_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000508_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000509_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000511_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN (CASE WHEN FLODS_101000512_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS IS NULL 
                      THEN 'No Payment Status' ELSE FLODS_101000512_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) ELSE FLODS_101000511_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) 
                      ELSE FLODS_101000509_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) ELSE FLODS_101000508_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) 
                      ELSE FLODS_101000489_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) ELSE FLODS_101000488_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) 
                      ELSE FLODS_101000386_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END) ELSE FLODS_101000385_SPECIAL_UP_C00.PAYMENTSTATUS END AS 'Payment Status', 
<more columns inc. a couple more columns using similar case functions> 

FROM   FLODS_101000489_SPECIAL_UP_C00 FULL OUTER JOIN
                      FLODS_101000488_SPECIAL_UP_C00 FULL OUTER JOIN
                      FLODS_101000509_SPECIAL_UP_C00 FULL OUTER JOIN
                      FLODS_101000511_SPECIAL_UP_C00 full outer JOIN
                      FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00 ON FLODS_101000511_SPECIAL_UP_C00.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID = FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID full outer JOIN
                      FLODS_101000512_SPECIAL_UP_C00 ON 
                      FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID = FLODS_101000512_SPECIAL_UP_C00.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID FULL OUTER JOIN
```

etc etc

I am able to select table names & column names from: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, if this helps. I don't maintain these tables. Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide us with some examples (simplified ones would be best probably)?  I'm not sure I can visualize what you are trying to do.

Comment: One thing that would probably help would be using COALESCE or at least ISNULL to avoid some of your case statements.

Comment: Are _you_ maintaining the list of tables?  I'm pretty sure SQL Server has some sort of information schema, although that would have everything, not just your reporting tables.  And what you want to do is possible, although you have to do it in two steps - one to retrieve the control data, and one to execute (after assembly).  This can either be done in a higher level language, or in a stored procedure.  This can get messy, though, as the indirection can be frustrating.  Specific examples may help, as there may be ways around this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand what you are doing and why you are doing it.  It isn't a good situation and the performance will be poor no matter what you do, but since you don't have control over the environment, we have to figure out how to work with what we have.

I have a few suggestions for improvements.  The first would be to use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) statement.  This returns the first non-null value.  You could replace your case statements with something like this:

```
COALESCE(value1, value2, value3, 'no value')
```

That would return the first non-null value.  The last option would be a string that you return as a last resort.  I believe your string is "No Payment Status".

The second option would be to place this logic into a UDF.  You could then call the UDF to get the value you want.  This abstracts out all of this logic and makes it cleaner.  It won't be more performant, per se, but it will be neater.

The third option would be to create some sort of temp table that you update based upon changed data in the tables.  You could store the collapsed data in one large table.  I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but it would probably make the performance better by doing the work once instead of each time you run the query.

Comment: Hi, I like the 3rd option (perhaps in conjunction with the 1st one too) as I would only have to update the temp table/view each time the database is updated (which isn't that often but is a hassle when it is). I guess I could edit my queries to join to this view so that I'm only updating one query - as opposed to 12... I was just hoping there was an automatic way of querying all similarly-named tables and looking for common column names. Many thanks, Guy.